# .Hide()/.Show() Span Issues - Bootstrap 3/MVC 5

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with the formatting of some buttons.

**Overview**: Initially an Edit and Delete button are shown. When Edit is pressed both of those button's `span` are `hidden`, and then Save and Cancel's `span` are `shown`. like this:

```
$(element).closest("td").find("span.item-save-button").show();
$(element).closest("td").find("span.item-cancel-button").show();
$(element).closest("td").find("span.item-edit-button").hide();
$(element).closest("td").find("span.item-delete-button").hide();
```

When Cancel is pressed, it flips back over to the original setup with Edit/Delete being `shown` and Save/Cancel `hidden`. Just the code above but with `.hide`/`.show` flipped.

This works fine for visibility, however the formatting for the Save/Cancel buttons is all messed up, yet it is situated EXACTLY the same as my Edit/Delete, so I suspect I am misunderstanding what is truly happening in the background.

**Visual Reference** - *Edit was clicked on the first three lines*.
[image]

I would like the Save and Cancel to appear like the Edit and Delete. I *believe* the issue has to do with me showing/hiding `spans`. I temporarily disabled the input boxes from appearing during the Edit process, and the buttons still miss-aligned for Save/Cancel, which ruled out my thoughts that maybe the text boxes were causing some strange padding/wrapping/whitespace/ect...

**View** - *`<td>` snippet that contains the buttons*.

```
<td class="col-md-3">
   <div class="pull-right">
      <span style="visibility:hidden" class="ID col-xs-0">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</span>

      <span class="item-save-button btn-group">
      <button type="button" onclick="saveFunction(this);" class="btn btn-success"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>Save</button>
      </span>

      <span class="item-cancel-button btn-group">
      <button type="button" onclick="cancelFunction(this);" class="btn btn-danger"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Cancel</button>
      </span>

      <span class="item-edit-button btn-group">
      <button type="button" onclick="editFunction(this);" class="btn btn-warning"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</button>
      </span>

      <!-- Modal Button-->
      <span class="item-delete-button btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@item.ID" onclick="deleteStart(this);">
      <span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete</button>
      </span>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix" /> //an attempt to clear any issues the 'pull-right' may have.
</td>
```

I have tried going through my *Inspector* to find the issue as well but I cannot seem to find anything useful.

I am still quite new to all of this (especially bootstrap), so any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE** (working solution, but would like help with the margin problem)

1. Gave all inputs a set `col-size` example: `@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Name, new { @class = "col-xs-10" })`
2. nested my buttons. Gave each button a `btn-group` tag .
3. At this point everything was organized correctly, but was margin'ed low for some reason. Added a `margin-top:-20px` to the `div pull-right` tag

   ```
   <td class="col-xs-3">
       <div class="pull-right" style="margin-top:-20px">
           <span style="visibility:hidden" class="ID col-xs-0">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</span>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-6">
                   <span class="item-save-button">
                       <button type="button" onclick="saveFunction(this);" class="btn btn-success btn-group"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>Save</button>
                   </span>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6">
                   <span class="item-cancel-button">
                       <button type="button" onclick="cancelFunction(this);" class="btn btn-danger btn-group"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Cancel</button>
                   </span>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-6">
                   <span class="item-edit-button">
                       <button type="button" onclick="editFunction(this);" class=" btn btn-warning btn-group"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</button>
                   </span>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6">
                   <!-- Modal Button-->
                   <span class="item-delete-button">
                       <button class="btn btn-danger btn-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@item.ID" onclick="deleteStart(this);">
                           <span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete
                       </button>
                   </span>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="clearfix" />
   </td>
   ```

So this makes everything aligned responsively, however I am confused as to why I need to this margin tag. What could be causing this?

Comment: My first guess is your styling is making one of the buttons a little too large for the defined area and causing the cancel button to wrap down to get more space.  Maybe try changing the columns to 'md' or increasing the width a little.

Comment: @L_7337 Hello! that code was actually a tid-bit incorrect (updated now) sorry haha. I removed the `width` after posting this as I was told that works against making a "responsive" website, and I just bumped up my col's to md, with the buttons being `col-md-4`. Still same issue unfortunately (the image is still how the application looks).

Comment: I'm not used to seeing bootstrap class put on TDs, so I'm wondering if the TD might be limiting the width??  `table`s also work against responsive design.  If you can reproduce this in a bootsnipp or jsfiddle, that would help.

Comment: Hmmm, okay! I can give it a shot in JSFiddle! May take a few though. Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: Here is an attempt to replicate it, but I never use JSFiddle and cannot figure out how to get my JQuery to work: http://jsfiddle.net/7VgaP/ Does this help at all?

Comment: One more thing.  The difference between the save and the edit rows is the Save rows have an `<input>` box inside them making the row height larger.  Try putting `input-sm` on those `input` text boxes to see if that has any affect.

Comment: Nothing changed. And as mentioned in the question I did a test by disabling the input change, meaning the labels stayed the same and only the buttons changed, and the buttons still shifted all weird.

Comment: Added an update if you have a guess on the margin issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this would probably be to use a combination of nested columns and the .btn-block class on the buttons themselves.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" onclick="saveFunction(this);" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>Save</button>
    </div><!-- /col-md-6 -->

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" onclick="cancelFunction(this);" class="btn btn-danger btn-block"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Cancel</button>
    </div><!-- /col-md-6 -->

</div><!-- /row -->
```

Comment: So I finally found a solution but it is still a little janky, as I am not sure why my margin needs to be adjusted. What I did was first apply a `col-size` of 8 on my inputs. I then nested my items as you suggested however I used `btn-group` (block wasn't aligning right). Finally on my `div pull-right` I added `margin-top:-20px` as everything was sitting low. Any idea why everything is pushed downward? (aka why do I need to use a minus margin?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using tables instead of divs? Bootstrap's default grid system works great without introducing a mess of table rows. Wouldn't surprise me at all of default browser formatting on tables or something in a custom stylesheet is what's making this a mess.

Comment: Yea I was told not to use them recently as well, but since I already have many things formatted to table attribu te's (td's/tr's) I will just leave this example project as is, but use tables from here on. Thank you for the help!